# Enabling https ssl wordpress plugin, some css stylesheets don't load on the first try. Issue happens only on a Mac

Tags: wordpress, macos, ssl, https

I have this issue that has been bothering me for about a month.  For a wordpress site, I installed the popular HTTPs plugin. I also converted all url's in the database and in php files to use https.

Now when I load the page in Chrome on a Mac, the styleesheets don't load on first try.  It says net::err connection refused.

This issue never appears in IE8-11 in Windows.  The links that say connection refused show the link is using https, the file permissions for the stylesheets in question are set to permission 644.  The directories containing them are 755.

I can also get into wordpress admin fine using https and my site that uses wordpress functions like is_user_logged_in.

When I disable/deactivate the https wordpress plugin, the issue disappears and everything loads fine.

On the Mac, when the issue happens, sometimes it loads on the first try, sometimes on the second, sometimes it takes 3 reloads for the page to fully load images/css.

I've also disabled the firewall on the Mac.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ok, fixed it, it seems it was my host (hostgator) a problem with the load balancer/reverse proxy or whatever it is, I'm still trying to wrap my understanding around it.</strike>

**Update**

Well it looks like it wasn't fixed, I had a false positive.  Still looking for a solution to this, if anyone can help, it would be very appreciated.

See: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ssl-insecure-needs-35-compatibility and this gist: https://gist.github.com/webaware/4688802.

After installing that gist as a wordpress plugin, the problem disappeared.

Also see: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/enqueued-css-javascript-not-changed-to-https

It also looked like one of the css stylesheets that didn't load, was using a background image from an http url, which is why it refused the connection, but on IE in windows, its not a problem.